# Substrate-Node-Template Docker crashes on M1 Macs

Tags: substrate-node-template, docker, macos

We are trying to run the docker solution available for the substrate-node-template but are hitting a crash, only on M1 Macs.

To repro, from the substrate-node-template repository, we added

```
touch .local
```

to line 9 of ./scripts/docker_run.sh

and run:

```
./scripts/init.sh
./scripts/docker_run.sh
```

On the M1 Mac, it is crashing while updating crates.io index and the output is as follows:

```
MacBook-Pro ~/d/substrate-node-template (main)> ./scripts/docker_run.sh
*** Start Substrate node template ***
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Container node-template                  Removed                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 ⠿ Network substrate-node-template_default  Removed                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Network substrate-node-template_default  Created                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
    Updating crates.io index
bash: line 1:     8 Killed                  cargo build --release
```

We have tried upping the RAM and swap space available in Docker to 16GB and 4GB respectively and this still failed. We are able to run these commands successfully on non-M1 macs.

Is anyone aware of a solution for this compatibility issue?

Answer (score 3):

That script is not compatible with Mac's.

- https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L6

It is compiled for Linux.

I ran into a similar conundrum recently:

- https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1336#issuecomment-1164730969